# How do I use svneverever?

Tags: svn, git-svn, dump, svn2git, svndump

I have a dump file (Your_dumpfile.dmp) and I am trying to use svneverever to check the format of the repository to help write rules for svn2git.

Svneverever sounds like a great tool, however, there isn't really any good documentation on how to use it.

So far I have installed it following https://github.com/hartwork/svneverever, and I have installed `pysvn` in the process, which is a dependency.

At the moment, when I try and run `svneverever --no-progress <Your_dumpfile.dmp file path>`, I get the following:

```
'svneverever' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How can I get the command to work and when it is, from where in my files do I run it from (e.g. in folder where dump file is... etc)?

Update:
I have realised in the svneverever folder, there is no executable.
[image: https://i.imgur.com/zssv9Vz.png]

There are some py files in the other folders. Am I supposed to run these?

This is what is already installed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BRVg.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zJS2.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKRE4.png]

Answer (score 1):

One thing about command line tools is that in order for your command line to use them, your command line has to be able to find them.

So in order to use svneverever, you have two options:

1) Specify the path to the executable. i.e.

```
C:/path/to/svneverever.exe --no-progress <Your_dumpfile.dmp file path>
```

The caveat to this is that you can simply navigate to this directory by doing:

```
C:\User\yourname> cd C:\path\to
C:\path\to> svneverever --no-progress <Your_dumpfile.dmp file path>
```

2) Add the path to wherever you installed svneverever to your PATH environment variable. Your user/system PATH is where your command line looks to find/run scripts, executables, etc. If this is an application that only you use, then you would add this PATH to your user PATH. If all users on your machine is using it, you will need to add it to your system PATH.

With option #2, you never need to specify the PATH or navigate to that directory in order to use it.

Comment: I just realised, in the svneverever folder, there is no executable. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @JonnySprouse So svneverever (the file) seems to just be an executable python file, so most of what I said still applies you just need to 1) Install Python, 2) Shift + Right Click inside of the folder you screenshotted, then "Open command window here". 3) If your python was installed correctly, you should then be able to run this script.

Edit: I actually take that back.. Looks like you already have python installed. I wish I had my computer in front of me to test for myself, you may need to start python and try running it with python's command line options?

Comment: From the command line, something like `C:\Python27\python.exe C:/path/to/svneverever` (again, unless python.exe is in your PATH you will need to specify the full path of the application). I'm not sure why svneverever doesn't have an extension. You may need to add a '.py' extension if it doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Installation
>
> If your Linux distribution of choice does not come with a package for
>   svneverever yet, you can install svneverever using pip from PyPI
>
> ```
> # pip instal svneverever
> ```
>
> or from a Git clone:
>
> ```
> # git clone https://github.com/hartwork/svneverever.git
> # cd svneverever
> # python setup.py install
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do both, `pip install` and running `setup.py`, as you can see in the output the second command just uninstalled what you had from the first command. This only makes sense if you want to have additional commit that are not in the officially released version.

I'm not really familiar with running the native windows python version, if I run python on windows then usually through Cygwin. I think you should either have svneverever now in `C:\Users\abdul-husseini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts` or `C:\Users\abdul-husseini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\`. But if you open the file you will see it is a text file that Windows cannot interpret as an executable, not like in Linux where this works fine.

So as this is a python script, call it like `python svneverever <remaining parameters` and it should work.